# Aache POI for excel color formatting

Tags: java, excel, apache, apache-poi

I am using APACHE POI 3.13 latest version, to convert a txt file to excel file and perform conditional formatting. But, instead of getting 3 color scales(like heatmap), all I get black color in the specified cells in the output excel file. I am not able to do 3 color scaling(color formatting). I checked on internet and found code from there, but I dont know what I m missing here.

Code

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFColorScaleFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFConditionalFormattingRule;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFontFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheetConditionalFormatting;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;   
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ComparisonOperator;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ConditionalFormattingThreshold.RangeType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class txtToExcel {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     LinkedList<String[]> text_lines = new LinkedList<>();
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\Personal\\arpitData\\Data\\Brian\\Matrix_all_beh_v2.txt"))) {
            String sCurrentLine;
            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text_lines.add(sCurrentLine.split("\\t"));                 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String fileName = "C:/Personal/arpitData/Data/Brian/Matrix_all_beh_v2_txt_to_excel.xls";
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Conditional_Formatting");
        int row_num = 0;
        for(String[] line : text_lines){
            Row row = sheet.createRow(row_num++);
            int cell_num = 0;
            for(String value : line){
                Cell cell = row.createCell(cell_num++);
                if(cell_num == 1 || row_num ==1){
                    cell.setCellValue(value);
                }
                else{
                    cell.setCellValue(new BigDecimal(value).doubleValue());
                }
            }
        }
        /* Access conditional formatting facet layer */

        HSSFSheetConditionalFormatting my_cond_format_layer = sheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
        /* Create a Rule */
        HSSFConditionalFormattingRule my_rule1 = my_cond_format_layer.createConditionalFormattingColorScaleRule();

        /* Define color formatting if rule is met */
        HSSFColorScaleFormatting my_rule_pattern1 = my_rule1.getColorScaleFormatting();
        my_rule_pattern1.getThresholds()[0].setRangeType(RangeType.MIN);
        my_rule_pattern1.getThresholds()[1].setRangeType(RangeType.PERCENTILE);
        my_rule_pattern1.getThresholds()[1].setValue((double) 50);
        my_rule_pattern1.getThresholds()[2].setRangeType(RangeType.PERCENTILE);
        my_rule_pattern1.getThresholds()[2].setValue((double) 95);
        my_rule_pattern1.getColors()[0].setARGBHex("FFFFFF");
        my_rule_pattern1.getColors()[1].setARGBHex("F6FCFF");
        my_rule_pattern1.getColors()[2].setARGBHex("FF6C6C");



        /* Create a Cell Range Address */
        CellRangeAddress[] my_data_range = {CellRangeAddress.valueOf("c2:I28")};

        /* Attach rule to cell range */
        my_cond_format_layer.addConditionalFormatting(my_data_range,my_rule1);

        /* Write changes to the workbook */
        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            workbook.write(out);
            out.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

}
```

My input file Matrix_all_beh_v2.txt is like

```
Total (2015/09/25)  Obesity weight gain Body weight/body fat    Adipocyte   Endocrine   PPAR    RXR GR
"3,3,5,5-Tetrabromobisphenol A" 26  7   9   10  0   10  2   1
7-Diethylamino-4-methylcoumarin 1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0  
"7,12-Dimethylbenz(a)anthracene"    140 84  20  16  10  16  6   9
"9-Aminoacridine, monohydrochloride, monohydrate"   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
"9,10-Dihydrobenzo[a]pyren-7(8H)-one"   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4-Dodecylphenol 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4-[3-(4-Acetyl-3-hydroxy-2-propylphenoxy)propoxy]phenoxy_acetic acid    47  4   7   11  2   32  9   0
```

Comment: I notice you didn't `setValue()` for the `setRangeType(RangeType.MIN)`.

Comment: I understand, that be the minimum value in the given row, so should be calculated dynamically. Nevertheless, I tried given a value, still didnt get it work. What I noticed, if I just  dont assign any threshold value or colors, and use empty rule, i still get the black colors.

Comment: One thing that is odd, I don't see a color pattern and pattern fore/background colors being set...  (Excel backgrounds have two parts to them with a pattern)   Also, cell values may need to be numeric instead of string.

Comment: The cell values are numeric. cell.setCellValue(new BigDecimal(value).doubleValue());

Comment: Did you try comparing your code to the Apache POI unit tests that cover conditional formatting?

Comment: I did that. The formatting where it changes the color of text, when its equal to some value, works fine. But this background color(3 color) formatting is not working

Comment: If you change your code from HSSF to XSSF, and write out a `.xlsx` file instead, does that work? i.e. is the problem with how you're calling POI, or a bug in the POI HSSF implementation?

Comment: It did work indeed, when I changed to XSSF from HSSF. Also, I had some missing libraries when I changed to XSSF. So, not sure if its the missing library issue or HSSF issue. But it did work with XSSF.

Comment: Sounds like a HSSF bug then. Any chance you could [report a bug](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=POI) and include a unit test to allow the problem to be reproduced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did work when I switch to XSSF from HSSF. Also, some of the jar libraries were missing, which I had to include to make it work.

Comment: XSSF needs additional jars to HSSF, [it's all detailed on the Apache POI website what needs what](http://poi.apache.org/overview.html#components)